# Is it possible to determine whether a number, can be made from 3 (or 4) others?

Tags: arithmetic

I am writing a numbers game involving 3 (or 4) die. The person has to make a number (from 1-25 for 3 die, and 1-100 for 4), and get from one end of a board to the other.

For example: Dice 1 = 3, Dice 2 = 5, Dice 3 = 4

Player chooses 60: (3 * 4) * 5

Is there an "easy" way to check this rather than going through all the possible arithmetic combinations? Please bare in mind that I have rusty high-school level mathematics knowledge!

Comment: Kindly use Mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on choices, you have 288 possibilities per set of rolls. But, depending on properties of operations used, you can cut out a lot of duplicates:

$$\begin{eqnarray}3\cdot4\cdot5=3\cdot 5\cdot 4=5\cdot4\cdot3=5\cdot3\cdot4=4\cdot5\cdot3=4\cdot3\cdot5\end{eqnarray}$$
and each of these have 2 parenthesized equivalents. addition with addition, also has these possibilities to eliminate without trying more than 1. etc. subtraction and division don't have as much freedom  but they do have some.

Comment: I am guessing i am going to have to work out these unique operations by hand?! i was hoping there would be an elegant solution! Thank you! :-)

Comment: out of 288 possibilities, my post eliminates 36 (12.5%)  or more.

Comment: That’s great. Every reduction helps! I just found out there can’t be an “easy” way to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be the number of 6-sided dices you roll, $x$ the number obtained as the product of the number displayed by each dice. Then
$$x= 2^{k_1} 3^{k_2} 5^{k_3}$$
with $k_i\in \mathbb{N}$ and $1\leq k_1 \leq n$, $1\leq k_2 \leq n$, $1\leq k_3\leq 2n$. The three integers $k_1, k_2, k_3$ are not independent as if e.g. $k_3=n$ then each dice rolled a 5, hence $k_1=k_2 =1$. Essentially, your number has no prime factor other than 2,3,5. This follows because the number is obtained by multiplying numbers from 1 to 6 and 4=2*2, 6=2*3. So e.g. no 42 as 42=7*3*2.

Comment: Thank you. I should have mentioned in the question the number generated by the player can be calculated by using any arithmetic function - i.e. addition, subtraction, multiplication, division...

Answer (score 0):

I've just found this on StackOverflow - it looks like the problem is NP-complete - which i think means there can be no easy solution!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824843/how-to-check-if-a-number-can-be-represented-as-a-sum-of-some-given-numbers

Comment: that's  called the subset sum problem, but we can fill in the gaps with other arithmetic here.